# how to upload file from codeigniter app to dropbox

Tags: php, codeigniter, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a controller to upload image to my web server. I want to upload that image to dropbox as well during the process. how would I do it?

This is my simple upload.php controller:

```
function index() {
    // get the binary data
    $file = file_get_contents("php://input");

    // prepare new name for upload image
    $name =rand().time().'jpg';

    $path = site_url('photo');

    // save to server directory
    file_put_contents($path.$name, $file);

    // save the name and id of the post to post photo table
    $input =  array(    'name' => $name,
                        'post_id'=> $id
                    );

    $this->db->insert('post_photo', $input);

}
```

Comment: A good start would be to look at the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php) or even plugins written specifically for codeigniter, [like this one](https://github.com/jimdoescode/CodeIgniter-Dropbox-API-Library)

Comment: Does dropbox support email to upload files like Imgur? that would be pretty easy to set up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blogpost has complete tutorial
how to use Dropbox api with codigniter using [**THIS**](https://github.com/jimdoescode/CodeIgniter-Dropbox-API-Library)  CodeIgniter-Dropbox-API-Library

http://jimdoescode.blogspot.com/2011/07/codeigniter-dropbox-api.html

Answer (score -1):

try this its working good, for drop box create one new folder and just copy past the URL instead of" /upload " replace by  /drop box URL

```
    $route=$_FILES['file_name']['name'];
    //var_dump($route);
    $target=realpath(APPPATH.'../uploads');
    $target=$target.'/'.$route;
    $tar=$route;
    $path=base_url().'uploads/'.$route;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'],$target))
        echo "uploaded";
    else
        echo "not";
```

Comment: Won't work because it's not on the same server, not to mention the fact that dropbox wouldn't accept it.